# Why is Python giving me a error from a incorrect path?

Tags: python, windows-xp, python-2.5

Ok, so this is really strange...
I run Python 2.5 on Windows XP, and I used easy_install to get the library java2python. I tried to run j2py.py, but whenever I do, it gives me this error:

```
C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages>j2py.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\j2py.py", line 16, in 
    from java2python.compiler import Module, buildAST, transformAST
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\__init__.py", line 9, in 

  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\java2python-0.5.1-py2.5.egg\java2python\co
mpiler\block.py", line 16, in 
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\java2python-0.5.1-py2.5.egg\java2python\co
mpiler\visitor.py", line 15, in 
ImportError: cannot import name reduce
```

So I went into the java2python-0.5.1-py2.5.egg folder and deleted the importing of reduce. This would still cause a error, but I didn't know that at the time. I ran it again, and it have me the EXACT SAME ERROR even though that line had been erased. I moved the java2python folder OUT of the of the java2python-0.5.1-py2.5.egg directory and into the site-packages directory, and it gave me the same errors. I removed the java2python-0.5.1-py2.5.egg from the easy_install.pth, and the same errors. I even did this command in the same command prompt:

```
C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages>cd c:\python25\lib\site-packages\java2python-0.5.1
-py2.5.egg\java2python\compiler
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I just don't get it. Why is this happening?

Comment: I have a funny feeling if you were to upgrade your rather outdated version of Python, things will work and rainbows will bloom. There will be world peace. Kittens will worship you as their god and unicorns will fly through the air. In short, all good things happen if you upgrade to the latest version of Python.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid You may be right, except for the kittens and rainbows segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That reduce is imported indicates that java2python was made and tested on a newer version of python than 2.5. 
That the error persists after the delete is probably because the visitor.py[c] was still in your path and not updated for some reason. Especially since it was still there after you completely removed the `.egg`

I would have tried to import visitor and then use `vistory.__file__` to see the actual file position of the file being loaded.